# Vagrant workflow

Tags: vagrant, chef-infra, puppet

Hi i was trying to understand what exactly is done when running

```
vagrant up
```

my reason for that is that in my case we need to install a lot of utilities.
i.e Version control tools, build tools, ide, etc... 
which takes a lot of time.

so actually i wanted a 'box' with all those tools.
After i have clean environment and got all tools, i would like to  make CI for our product.

If i will reinstall all utilities it should take a lot of time. so what i am actually need is just installing and testing our product. 
How should i handle that ??
create my own box? does the command reinstall all utilities when we make CI ??

what i actually need are 2 processes :

1.installing utilities for my vm. (once a month)

2.test our product (each commit\push to version control)

how can i achieve that  ?

Comment: You are basically asking for a How-To guide on one of **the** main use case for Vagrant. As such, this question is too broad for Stack Overflow, or can be construed as a question for a link to appropriate documentation, which is not valid either. What has your own research turned up? What are your issues with the common guides?

Comment: didn't got your question well.  
Anyway my use case is for enterprise product that have a lot of dependencies. so installing those dependencies each time can take a lot of time while what i actually want to do on CI is test my product.

If i will take it to numbers lets say , installing dependencis can take 3 hours. while installing the product can take 1 hour. 
what i actually want is a VM with all my dependencies to test my product. more than that ,a possibility to make changes (versions mostly) for my dependencies, which happens once a month.

Answer (score 1):

For the first time, `vagrant up` will create a new VM for you, pulling the box image if needed, and it will provision it with what you configured in the Vagrantfile. In the provision configuration, you can tell Chef or Puppet to install all the utilities and tools that you need.

When you suspend or halt the VM, the next time you do a `vagrant up` it will only bring that VM back up. It will **not** install or try to provision it again.

You can force it with `vagrant up --provision` or just `vagrant provision`.

This usually works well in a development environment.

In a CI environment, it may not be possible to have the VM already provision, forcing you to run the provisioning step every time. You can achieve what you need packaging your own box with the tools already installed, essentially creating a golden or base image.

Just be extra careful so that the CI environment don't differ for what you have in production.

Comment: it means that each month, we need to make new VM ... 
So why would i like to use vagrant ?!?! 
i wanted to reduce the time for this installations...

Answer (score 0):

All depend on the setting in `Vagrantfile`

you have `modules` folder to put all puppet modules, `manifests` folder with `site.pp` and Vagrantfile as below under same place.

Give you a sample of `Vagrantfile` I used mostly.

```
VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION = "2"

Vagrant.configure(VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION) do |config|

  config.vm.box = "precise64"
  config.vm.box_url = "https://cloud-images.ubuntu.com/vagrant/precise/current/precise-server-cloudimg-amd64-vagrant-disk1.box "

  config.vm.provision :puppet do |puppet|
    puppet.module_path = "modules"
    puppet.manifests_path = "manifests"
    puppet.manifest_file  = "site.pp"
  end

  config.vm.define :www do |config|
     config.vm.host_name = "www.example.com"
     config.vm.network :private_network, ip: "192.168.1.2"
  end

  config.vm.define :db1 do |config|
     config.vm.host_name = "db1.example.com"
     config.vm.network :private_network, ip: "192.168.1.4"
  end

end
```

So after run `vagrant up www` or `vagrant up db1` it will start the box with `puppet apply` directly. You can understand this way as `puppet masterless`

Vagrant just make the box up running from linux image defined in `config.vm.box_url` as a simple fresh linux box, and mount your local folder to new box's `/vagrant` folder, then hand over to puppet. How the server to be provisioned, will be depended on site.pp (define applications on each node) and puppet modules. The command is similar as

```
puppet apply --modulepath /vagrant/module /vagrant/manifests/site.pp
```

So if your puppet modules are fine, your new box will automatically have all utilities and products installed. Then you run `vagrant ssh www` or `vagrant ssh db1`, you can login it and start working.

You can put your local folder with `moduels`, `manifests` folders and `Vagrantfile` to version control (such as git). So developers can clone the git repository to their own computer easily.

Comment: i didnt understand the last part regards  the 'puppet apply' since i am not familiar with puppet at all.  why do i need to make 2 boxes :db1,www.  
can  you please explain yourself more since i am just researcing right now for technology to make what i wanted to, and i am not familiar with it.

Comment: I gave samples to create two boxes, then you can get idea how to create more boxes.